# Test reg-tests-1d.R failing for R v3.6.2

Tags: r

While running the make check command for **R v3.6.2** on Linux **Ubuntu 16.04**. I am facing below error for test case `reg-tests-1d.R`

```
Error in assertCondition(expr, "warning", .exprString = d.expr) :
  Failed to get warning in evaluating (x[60:68]%%3)
Calls: <Anonymous> -> assertCondition
Execution halted
```

The error occurs at step assertWarning in `/R-3.6.2/tests/reg-tests-1d.R`

```
}) # larger x suffer from cancellation (well, warning too early now):
tools::assertWarning(x[60:68] %% 3)
```

Is there any workaround to resolve the same. And how crucial is the warning in this case.

Comment: Can I ask what hardware you're on? I can reproduce this on a Jetson Nano (Ubuntu 18.04, arm64 hardware) but I *can't* reproduce it on my laptop (Arch Linux, x86_64 hardware).

I'm going to try this with different compilers on the Nano but I'm not sure when I'll get to it.

Comment: See my issue <https://github.com/znmeb/edgyR/issues/3> for my tracking. This may be a gcc bug - Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 have older compilers than Arch (gcc 9.2.0-4).

Comment: In any event, the fact that it does not fail on Arch / x86_64 / gcc 9.2.0-4 indicates that the R environment that produced this error message should not be used.

Comment: @znmeb I am working on  Ubuntu 16.04 s390x. I tried upgrading gcc to version 9.2.0-4. However the build failed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved in the latest release v4.0.0. The mentioned test passes successfully.